# Why do we pass a reference to the object as an argument to the overloaded output operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

Why is it so important to be the reference and not just a copy of the object? For instance:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const X & _class);
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const X   _class);
```

What do we lose/win if we don't pass it as a reference?

Comment: otherwise it will create a copy of the ostream and perform your logic on that, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: This is what im asking this is a simple output overloading!I dont want to change anything i just want to cout.

Comment: I dont want to change the object this is output overloading

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary because `X` objects are not copyable. If `X` has a non-trivial copy-constructor then it is an optimization. In other cases, it is a micro-optimization that may even be a "pessimization".

Answer (score 2):

In general, `const&` is preferred because, except for easy-to-copy types (Such as basic types) , copying is expensive (I recall, not always). But note that pass by value means the internal value of the function has nothing to do with the value passed to the function. That allows the compiler to do some assumptions and perform better optimizations in some cases. So in some cases, passing by value is better.

One of such cases is when you need a copy of the passed parameter:

```
void f( T param )
{
    /* do something mutable with param */
}
```

In that cases, passing by value is prefereable over passing by const reference + hand copy, because the compiler could do assumptions based on value-semantics, and optimize the code. The rule is: Let the compiler decide **how** to pass by value.

In the case of streams, C++ streams are not copyable, thats why they are passed by reference. Is a non-const reference because IO operations change the internal state of the stream.

Comment: +1 And a `const` reference makes it clear to others that the output operator does not mutate its operand.

Answer (score 2):

"reasonable pessimism" would summarise why we do this, and indeed why we prefer to pass a reference for any non-trivial object for which we don't need a copy.

We can be reasonably pessimistic that for anything other than a native type, making a copy is inefficient when compared to accessing the object via a reference.

We can also expect that not all objects are copyable, so writing a function that demands that our arguments are copyable is not only a possible inefficiency, it may well also lead to a program that cannot be compiled.

We can also expect that some objects' copy constructors will have side-effects (such as the deprecated auto_ptr). If we just want to query the state of an object, these side-effects would be undesirable. In the case of the auto_ptr, they would result in the deletion of the object controlled by the auto_ptr at the end of your function. Catastrophic.

The general rule would be:

- If you are just going to read the object, pass a const reference
- If you are going to modify the object, pass a reference (or pointer).
- If you are definitely going to make a copy of the object, pass it by
  value.
- If you might make a copy, then either pass by const reference
  (optimistic that we won't need to make a copy) or by value
  (reasonably confident that the copy is required).

Answer (score 1):

in the general case, passing a `const&` to a function is more efficient since it avoids making a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is obvious. Because if you do not, then the actual object will not be modified. Instead a copy will made and the copy will be modified, then later the copy will get destroyed.

Comment: The argument is const, so it won't be modified whether it's passed by reference or by value.

Comment: OP is referring to the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not const reference, then you need define a copy constructor to get it correct, and calling copy constructors would cost more memory and CPU obviously which is really unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it straight. When you pass a reference of the object and modify the object contents in the definition of the overloaded operator, the same will get reflected on the object. For example: (Though a + operator is never overloaded this way for complex numbers, the example is just to prove a point). Say for an overloaded + operator

```
complex1& operator+(complex1 a)
    {
        a.real = a.real+1;
        real=real+a.real;
        img=img+a.img;
        return *(this);
    }

int main()
{
    complex1 c1(1,2),c2(2.4,6.3);
    complex1 c3 = c1+c2;
    cout<<c2;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the changes made in real part of c2(i.e. addition of 1) will not be reflected when it is printed and will still be 2.4 if a reference is not passed. Thus passing a reference will increase the value of its real part by 1.

**Secondly,** passing a reference is more efficient as you pass only a reference to that object unlike passing by value where all the properties of the object gets copied.